# Add select dropdown in DOM of angular datatables and refresh after fire change action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I add select dropdown in DOM of angular-datatable existing in github [Click here for Referecnce](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables)

```
app.controller('dataTableCrtl', dataTableFunction);
```

app.js

```
function dataTableFunction($scope, $state, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $timeout) {
  var campoAno = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.contentano' ) );
  campoAno.prepend('<select class="form-control item-acoes" name="exercicio" id="selectano"><option value='2015'>2015<option><option value='2016'>2016<option></select>
  var vm = this;
  vm.dtInstance = {};
  vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('ajax', {
     url : url+'dt_docs.php',
     type : 'GET',
     contentType : 'application/json'
  })
  .withDataProp('aaData')
  .withOption('processing', true)
  .withOption('serverSide', true)
  .withOption('order', [0, 'desc'])
  .withDOM("<'row hidden-print'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6 contentano divbusca'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row form-actions hidden-print'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>")

  function changeAno() {
    $('#selectano').bind('change', function(){
      vm.dtInstance.reloadData();
    });
  }
}
```

page.html

```
<table datatable="" class="table table-condensed table-hover" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" dt-instance="showCase.dtInstance" class="row-border hover" width="100%"></table>
```

result

[image]

I'm try change select and send data of option selected and reload or refresh the Datatble angular. But don't reload or refresh my page on select dropdown of year.

Comment: Syntax error: `vm.dtInstance = {}; .withOption('ajax', { `

Comment: Ok thanks for this, I forgot when i copy the code. But my ask is for solve other problem. refresh datatable on change option in select